# Connecting to a parse database via webhooks

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, webhooks, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to connect my mailparser.io account to my Parse Database. Everything I have found says to do so via Parse Cloud Code and webhooks. However, I havent been able to find any examples of what the code might look like and what URL to send the data to.

Comment: From looking at the marilparser.io docs, it looks like they can hit a custom webhook on your server when necessary. Checkout: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webhooks, which has a pretty good code example of how to setup a webhook in Cloud Code. Note that the example assumes you have setup express as well.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up a webhook in mailparser.io, you can choose to send the data as "form data". When you do this, the parsed data fields will be available in the parse.com API like this:

```
var something = req.body.fieldname_text;
```

You should be able to see all fields by doing a

```
console.log(req.body);
```